# Unable to start Apache - (98)Address already in use: AH00073

Tags: apache, lamp, bitnami

Recently decided to change my VM type on my Google Cloud account, but in the process of changing the VM it seems something has gone wrong as I'm now unable to start Apache as I keep getting the following error:

(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

I have tried to do the following steps:

```
netstat -ltnp | grep :80
```

This would return the following:

```
tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1047/apache2
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo kill -9 1047
```

(1047 - pid no)

(the pid that appears on your particular instance.)

Restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But this doesn't help, i keep getting the same error. In fact if I run netstat right after killing the process, a new process with an incremental id of 1 pops up.

Also ran

```
grep Listen /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

To see if there are multiple processes on the same port, that does not seem to be the case :-(

I'm stuck, help :-(

Mikael

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this out in the end by changing the port for Apache, not sure what or why port 80 was taken, but I followed these steps which did the trick:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/redmine/administration/configure-port/#http-port

Cheers,
Mika